# Can not run makefile with Cygwin make

Tags: makefile, cygwin, gnu

I'm trying build my app with Cygwin terminal and make which was installed from Cygwin packages (GNU make). But after first try I got error like 'No rule to make target ...'. So I try to investigate why it is not working with this Cygwin GNU make version 4.1 and it is working with my current GNU make V3.81.

I found out that main problem is with rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:%.c
  do a compilation (working with 3.81)
```

To make it work for Cygwin I need to change it into:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:%.c
  compilation done

%.c:
  do a compilation here (working with 4.1)
```

So for Cygwin version I need to split rule %.o:%.c. And if I will do it it is no more working for my older version of GNU make 3.81.

Is my syntax really wrong or there is so big difference between these two versions.

Also I found out that v3.81 is incredible slow in case I am in corporate network where some background tasks are running.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the "No rule to make target" error just means that it can't find the file you're trying to compile. That could be because the file doesn't exist, or because you're specifying the wrong place to look for the file/compile the file to.

It looks like you are missing the $(OBJ_DIR) in front of the %.c target.

**Try this instead:**

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:%.c
  compilation done

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.c:
  do a compilation here (working with 4.1)
```